# Trigonometrical equation : bounds in graph

Tags: trigonometry

I was looking at the following graph [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iyz3erfub9), and regarding the sets of two functions' given at:
(i)$\,\,\,\,\,$#4,5 given as: $y= \tan a.x \{0<x<cos a\}, \,\, y= \tan a.x \{cos a<x<0\}$;
 (ii)$\,\,$ #6,7 given as: $x = \cos(a)\{0<y<\sin(a)\}, \,\, x = \cos(a)\{\sin(a)<y<0\}$; 
(iii)#10,11 given as: $y = 0\{0< x < \cos a\},\,\, y = 0\{\cos a< x < 0\}$.

This is causing confusion, & want to know the significance of the bounds given.
 I mean that why two separate intervals are given rather than, say replacing the bounds given at: 
(i)  $\,\,\,\,$#4,5 by a single one as: $y= \tan a.x \{-cosa<x<cos a\}$; 
(ii) $\,$ #6,7 by simply one as : $x = \cos(a)\{-\sin(a)<y<\sin(a)\}$; 
(iii) #10, 11 by a single one as : $y = 0\{-\cos a< x < \cos a\}$.

Comment: If you turn on and off each of the partial graphs, you will see which part of the graphic it represents. Surely you will then understand why the bounds were defined that way.

Comment: @MattiP. I tried each combination separately, but could not.

Comment: Also, if you replace some of the equations by your own suggestions, you will see that the graphs change to something that the one who created it certainly didn't intend.

Comment: @MattiP. Definitely, but unable to find out still. I tried for around an hour before posting. May be, need a long break and then work with paper and pencil to understand.

Comment: @MattiP. Sorry, not read your first comment properly. Am following it now. That is easier and better, as to see changes by my new way is much more difficult when cannot understand the author's graph.

Comment: @MattiP. Understood, was easy. Have one sample graph for modifying function at: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/slhhqx9349. Thanks.